# Where are the Azure Databricks DBFS datasets stored?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I upload data to the Azure Databricks and I can see there are datasets in the DBFS list, but I cannot find any datasets in the resource group that Databricks belongs to.

Where are Azure Databricks DBFS datasets stored?

Also, if I create Delta Lake, how can I call the delta lake from Azure Data factory? I cannot see where the delta lake is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Where are Azure Databricks DBFS datasets stored?**

The ***Default storage location*** in ***DBFS*** is known as the ***DBFS root***.
You can find any datasets in  ***`/databricks-datasets`***: See [***special DBFS Root location***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#special-dbfs-root-locations).

[image: Ref1]

**Databricks File System (DBFS)** is a distributed file system mounted into an **Azure Databricks workspace** and available on Azure Databricks clusters. DBFS is on top of scalable object storage ADLS gen2.

> **how can I call the delta lake from Azure Data factory?**

**You can refer to this video and also Follow below References :**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqQRwsF_Ps

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--important-information-about-dbfs-permissions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-datasets